# Missing some options

Tags: fluid-simulation

Hi I Want to make Water in Blender but I do not have all options all I need in Fluid menu[image]

Comment: Hi, maybe you could indicate which option you need to have?

Comment: Fluid simulations had a massive rework in the last release of Blender (2.82). Because that release is very recent, the vast majority of tutorials are for the old system. You can either use an older version of Blender (2.81 should be fine), or find a very recent tutorial/documentation (try with the keyword "mantaflow")